# How to dynamically start an android service?

Tags: android, android-intent, service, broadcastreceiver, nfc

I want my android service to be automatically started when my mobile entered into a NFC Reader's RF field? How to do that? Please give suggestions....

Comment: Is the app that detects that it is in the NFC RF field run as a Activity or as a Service.  I image it probably is already running as a service so there is really no need to start another service.

Comment: I want to write my custom service which will launch an activity as soon as RF field detected....

Answer (score 0):

There are three intents you can declare in manifest for your activity: [`ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED) , [`ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED) and [`ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED).

Android will start Activities declaring these intents when a NFC tag is discovered by the device.